# Is there any way to get the real url from the omnibox when on a chrome error page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am currently trying to make an extension that will auto unsuspend tabs that used to be suspended with the great suspender.

```js
function unsuspend() {
    if(document.location.href.startsWith("chrome-extension") &&
       document.location.href.indexOf("/suspended.html#") > -1) {
            unsuspendurl = document.location.href.substr(document.location.href.lastIndexOf("&uri=")+5);
            return unsuspendurl;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when an extension is uninstalled you get an error page that is the document (chrome-error://chromewebdata/).

I have tried to find if anyone has a way to get the omnibox text but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think extensions can't access other extensions pages. So I had to do this semi-automatically in my attempt to solve this :) https://gist.github.com/JLarky/0385d22305c86ed5ca05b254a1e902ac

Comment: After trying to make my extentions work I came to the same conclusion that extensions cannot access other extensions pages.

Comment: Though, there may be a way for the extension to see the URL and close the tab and open a new one with the real URL